# Features workflow issue with deleting a field

Tags: 7, features

Suppose I have a content type `Person` with fields: `Name`, `Age`, `Email`

This content type is controlled by a Feature called `test` so I can source control it and push it to the live site.

My workflow goes like this:

- I add a new field on `Person` called `Phone`
- locally I do: `drush fu test -y`
- I edit the `test.info` to increase the version number
- I commit the changes to my repository
- I push the feature to the live site (copy the feature files)
- on the live site I do: `drush fr test -y`
- on the live site I do: `drush cc all`

Then the new field appears on the live site's `Person`.

If on the first step I remove a field of `Person` the field will not be deleted from the live site. How do I solve this? I don't want to have to manually delete it from the UI on the live site.
Is this workflow correct?

Comment: Use drush fu test -y --version-increment to automatically increment the version number

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a double edged sword, it's like this to prevent data deletion which is *always* a good thing. There's nothing really to solve, this is expected behaviour.

It's the same workflow we use and have been doing for over a year and it works really well. I'd say it's correct but that's a very subjective answer.

Comment: And if I really wanted to delete the field? Should I look into update hooks? (I'm a D7 newbie).

Comment: Update hooks would be ideal, or manually remove it.

Comment: OK, I could also do `drush field-delete field`

Comment: @cherouvim So you'd have to do that every time you recreate a feature?

Comment: A hook_update_N() in the feature's .install file would work.

Answer (score 10):

The correct way to remove Features-created content is via [hook_update_N](http://api.drupal.org/hook_update_N) (which should be implemented in the file `your_module.install`).

---

The main idea with Features is to manage configuration with code. Using `hook_update_N` is consistent with that, since the field deletion is in code (which can be managed with version control) — whereas the equivalent command `drush field-delete field` is not being called from managed code; it's a separate command-line step you need to perform (and to remember to perform).

Comment: Why? Won't `drush field-delete field` work well?

Comment: Sure, that would work, and may be a simpler solution.  But the main idea with Features is to manage configuration with code.  Using `hook_update()` is consistent with that, since the field deletion is in code (which can be managed with version control) — whereas the drush command is not being called from managed code; it's a separate command-line step you need to perform (and to remember to perform).

Comment: In which file of a feature will I use hook_update()? hook_update() takes a node object as parameter, so it is not possible to provide it a node object while enabling the feature.

Comment: @subhojit777: Oops, I linked to the wrong hook documentation page.  I just fixed the link; please see the docs for `hook_update_N`.

Comment: @smokris :) I mentioned that hook in my answer

Comment: How would hook_update_N work with multiple enable/disable of the feature? Would that be applied every time?

Answer (score 2):

Create a new file called "your_feature_name.install"

Inside the file declare [hook_update_N](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_update_N/7), there you can use [field_delete_field()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.crud.inc/function/field_delete_field/7) and specify the name of field that you want to delete as parameter.

Run update.php and the fields will be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `field_phone` in other areas, you might just want to remove it from your Person content type, but not delete it entirely from your site. Manually create a `YOUR_FEATURE_NAME.install` file in your feature's folder like so:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_update_N().
 *
 * Removes field_phone from Person content type.
 */
function YOUR_FEATURE_NAME_update_7001() {
  if ($instance = field_info_instance('node', 'field_phone', 'person')) {
    field_delete_instance($instance);
  }
  field_purge_batch(500);
  features_revert_module('YOUR_FEATURE_NAME');
}
```

If you were deleting this from a Person Paragraph instead of a Person Content Type, you could change the first conditional statement to something like this:

```
if ($instance = field_info_instance('paragraphs_item', 'field_phone', 'person')) {
  ...
}
```