# weird features behavior - constantly adding and removing entries from taxonomy.inc

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, features

I'm using `features` and [I commit the features module to my repository](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/27442/6286) to track changes.

Every now and then (after `drush fu foobar`) I see the following change to the `foobar.features.taxonomy.inc` file:

```
@@ -16,8 +16,6 @@
       'hierarchy' => '0',
       'module' => 'taxonomy',
       'weight' => '0',
-      'language' => 'und',
-      'i18n_mode' => '1',
       'metatags' => array(),
       'rdf_mapping' => array(
         'rdftype' => array(
@@ -42,8 +40,6 @@
       'hierarchy' => '0',
       'module' => 'taxonomy',
       'weight' => '0',
-      'language' => 'und',
-      'i18n_mode' => '1',
       'metatags' => array(),
       'rdf_mapping' => array(
         'rdftype' => array(
...
```

Note the removals in the above diff starting with `-`. That takes place at the same time for all of my 15 taxonomy vocabularies.

After some development and in the next `drush fu foobar` those exact lines are added back.

In the meantime of that cycle:

- I haven't touched anything on those taxonomies
- I haven't updated `features` (I use the latest)

Any idea why this is happening?

**Edit: More info**
After the offending lines are added in the `foobar.features.taxonomy.inc` file if I do a `drush cc all` then I get the following output in the console:

```
Reset language for all terms.

Reset language for all terms.

[...]

Reset language for all terms.
```

That is 15 times if I have 15 taxonomy vocabularies.

Comment: Cache ?? I have faced these kind of issues many times.. After features update Clear drupal cache and check...

Answer (score 0):

[Taxonomy Edge](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_edge) optimizes tree functions for taxonomies. It provides a transitive closure table data model for easily managing hierarchical terms. It was created to avoid recursive functions when fetching all children, and to avoid the not-quite-so-scalable memory footprint of taxonomy_get_tree().

The provided patch contains overrides for the core module Taxonomy in regards to taxonomy_get_tree() and taxonomy_select_nodes().